# Number of configurations of coins on a chessboard

Tags: combinatorics

For each square of a standard 8 × 8 chessboard, you either put a coin on it or leave it empty. You also have to guarantee that each row and column will contain an odd number of coins. How many such configurations of coins are there?

Notice: the chessboard is unlabeled, but the left-bottom-corner is black.

Comment: Wow, the $3 \times 3$ case isn't that easy to deal with either.

Comment: Rotation through $180^\circ$ complicates the problem, we no longer have the simple $2^{49}$ answer.

Comment: I thought about some recursive dependency between the 2x2, 4x4 and 8x8 case, but didn't notice any. Also I have seen, that having a valid configuration, you can switch any rows between themselves and you get again a valid configuration (the same holds for columns).

Comment: Just $2^{49}$ for the labeled case, I believe. (The answer can't be larger than $2^{64}$)

Comment: Yes, what I wrote above (edited in time) was a hybrid of $2^{7^2}$ and $2^{49}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas where do you get the $2^{49}$ from? What is the simle case?

Comment: @AndreiI $\binom{8}{1} + \binom{8}{3} + \binom{8}{5} + \binom{8}{7} = 2^7$ choices for each of the first seven columns, the eighth is forced

Comment: @Andrei 2x2 blocks of 1s generate all arrangements with even rows and columns

Comment: @user7530 you mean we just have to substract from the number of total possible configurations (even & odd) the number of odd-configurations?

Comment: @Andrei the even-rows-and-columns diagrams are in bijection with the odd-rows-and-columns (add a diagonal of 1s). I think the former are easier to work with.

Comment: You can fill in all but bottom row and rightmost column arbitrarily. It is then easy to show that there is a unique extension to the bottom row and rightmost column that satisfies the oddness condition. (The only thing that needs proving is that the bottom right corner can be filled consistently,) By simple case I mean the board cannot be rotated $180^\circ$. It has a labelled north side, south side.

Comment: For the 3x3 case you can use Burnside's lemma. There are 4 configurations left invariant under 180deg rotation and out of $16 = 2^4$ possibilities you get $1/2 (4 + 16) = 10$ solutions, right? Here the number should be $2^{48}$ + half the number of solutions left invariant by turning, but the numbers are bigger

Comment: @AndréNicolas why does it has a labelled north & south side? If you rotate it exactly 180 degrees, then you get the same chessboard (but probably a different configuration)

Comment: Now I think it's $2^{48}+2^{25}-2^{24}.$

Comment: @Andrei: If we allow rotation, we have to count separately the configurations that have symmetry across the long black diagonal and the ones that do not. Still doable, just more complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can think of the chess board as an $8\times 8$ matrix in $F_2$. The number of configurations with an odd number of coins on each row/column is the same as the number of configurations with an even number of coins on each (the bijection is given by adding the identity matrix), and it will be easier to work with the latter.

We want to count the number of matrices that obey the row/column parity condition, up to rotations by 180 degrees. The number is therefore given by
$$(T-S)/2 + S,$$
where $T$ is the total number of matrices satisfying the parity condition, and $S$ is the number of such matrices with 180-degree symmetry.

Claim: Each matrix $M$ with even row/column sums is uniquely specified by $49$ binary digits $\alpha_{i,j}$, with
$$M = \sum_{i=1}^7 \sum_{j=1}^7 \alpha_{i,j} A_{i,j},$$
where $A_{i,j}$ is the matrix that is zero except for a $2\times 2$ block of ones whose top-left corner is at $(i,j)$ (and lower-right corner at $(i+1,j+1)$), and the sum is taken in the space of matrices with coefficients in $F_2$, ie the coefficients are taken mod 2.
Proof: Start at the top-right corner of $M$ and work your way left-to-right, top-to-bottom.

The above gives us $T = 2^{49}$. We can also compute the number of symmetric matrices with even row/column sum: we can pair off each $A_{i,j}$ with the corresponding basis matrix $A_{8-i,8-j}$ that you get by rotating $A_{i,j}$ by 180 degrees. Only one basis matrix gets mapped to itself: $A_{4,4}$. Therefore you have two choices for $\alpha_{4,4}$, and two choices for each pair of remaining coefficients, for a total of $S=2^{25}$ choices.

The answer is therefore $2^{48} + 2^{25} - 2^{24} = 2^{48} + 2^{24}.$

Comment: @Cocopuffs Ha, yes you can. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting ideas, but I have some questions. I may agree that $T=2^{49}$ but how do you write the following matrix as a sum of $A_{ij}$ ?: \begin{array}{lcr}
\mbox{0} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
\mbox{0} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
\mbox{0} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\mbox{0} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\mbox{0} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\mbox{0} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\mbox{0} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\mbox{0} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}

Comment: $\alpha_{1,2} = \alpha_{1,3} = \alpha_{1,4} = \alpha_{1,5} = 1$, the rest zero. The sum is being taken mod 2, which I'll make more clear.

Comment: It makes sense with $F_2$. Notice: in order $\alpha_{1,2}$ through $\alpha_{1,5}$ to equal 1 in the last comment, $A_{i,j}$ has the top-left corner instead of the top-right, isn't it?. I lack the notion of $F_2$, could you add this piece of information please?

Comment: Very well explained! Thank you!!!

Comment: Yes, top left. I've fixed it.